# Toast.makeText cause an error in setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

The following code can run correctly, but an error will occur when I use `Toast.makeText(this,((TextView) view).getText().toString(), 2000).show();` I don't know why. I try to use `Toast.makeText(this.parent,((TextView) view).getText().toString(), 2000).show();`, it also cause error.

```
private void InitControl() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]));
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerFolder.setAdapter(adapter1);

    spinnerFolder.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    ((TextView) view).getText().toString(), 2000).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
});
```

Comment: You said your code runs perfectly, so what is the problem? One thing to mention: if you use `this` in the code, then you are referring to the instance of `new OnItemSElectedListener` not to the `MainActivity.this` which is what you have in the code it self. `this.parent` well that I don't know what that gets you lol :P

Comment: define 'error', post stacktrace.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adapter1.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString(),  2000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lv.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString(),  2000).show();
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

because you run it inside invalid context, `MainActicity.this` is not valid for showing a toast.

define a context outside the listener like

```
final Context context = this; //'this' should be your activity
```

and inside the listener call the toast like

```
 Toast.makeText(context,
                    ((TextView) view).getText().toString(), 2000).show();
```

additionally, the most proper way to do this is to define your own class that implements the `OnItemClickListener`, define a `Context` member variable and set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
(TextView) view).getText().toString()
```

by

```
spinnerFolder.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Toast duration is not a value that you put there, in seconds or milliseconds, it is a flag that you have to set, you have to put there [LENGTH_SHORT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT), or [LENGTH_LONG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG). This are flags, if you need a longer duration then length_long, you will have to use [notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)